# gem install sqlite3-ruby fails on cygwin

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cygwin, sqlite3-ruby

I am trying to install ruby on rails on cygwin but have hit a roadblock while creating a test app e.g.,

```
rails new my_test_app
```

Looks like my install (`ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-cygwin], rails 3.2.13, gem 2.0.6, rake 10.1.0`) had a gem missing -> sqlite3-ruby. Now the header file (`sqlite3.h`) is not found and I cannot specify config options which gem understands. Can someone please help me out ?

```
$ rails new test_ror_app1
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.7.7)
Using activesupport (3.2.13)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.13)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.13)
Using mime-types (1.23)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.14)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.13)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activerecord (3.2.13)
Using activeresource (3.2.13)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Using json (1.8.0)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (3.2.13)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using rails (3.2.13)
Using sass (3.2.10)
Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

    /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
        --enable-local
        --disable-local
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an
executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
        from extconf.rb:34:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 f
or inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_ma
ke.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

This was done successfully as can be seen below :

```
$ gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mswin32-60
1 gem installed
```

When I retry the creation the new test app, the same error as above (first) repeats.

Please help me solve this.
    TIA.

Update [1] : mkmf.log reveals this :
`/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypt`

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing via Rubygems, the output on the terminal may complain about not being able to find `sqlite3.h`. This is misleading. If you **check the `mkmf.log` file**, you may find that an entirely different header file is actually missing. Generally the header file can be installed via the corresponding Cygwin package. In my case, I made sure to install each of:

- `libcrypt-devel`
- `libsqlite3-devel`
- `libgmp-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by following 2 steps :-
a) cd to /usr/lib (where the libcrypto.a and libcrypto.dll.a files are located) 
b) make a local copy of libcrypto.a and rename to libcrypt.a

`Run gem install sqlite3`
`Run rails new my_app1`

Works so far ....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that gcc is not able to find "crypt" library mentioned by '-lcrypt' flag.
install "libcrypt-devel" package from cygwin packages...